# How do I write a robust multithreading map function?

Tags: python

I can apply this function successfully to parallelize function across a list:

```
def multiprocessing_run_func_with_list(func_now, list_now,threadingcount=8): 
    from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError
    with Pool(processes=threadingcount) as pool:
        results = pool.map(func_now, list_now)
        
    return results
```

However, when i switch to threading, Jupiter notebook just dies when running the following. (previously it runs well... not sure why it does not run well now...)

```
def multithreading_run_func_with_list(func_now, list_now,threadingcount=8): 
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    if threadingcount is not None:
        threads = ThreadPool(threadingcount) # Initialize the desired number of threads
    else:
        threads = ThreadPool(len(list_now)) # Initialize the desired number of threads
#     results = threads.map(func_now, list_now)
    results = threads.starmap(func_now, [(j,) for j in list_now])
 
    return results
```

Is there any error/ bettie way to call such multithreading?

Answer (score 1):

Python restricts multi-threading to avoid memory conflicts (it does so using the GIL). I would recommend you just use multi-processing and batching to make use of all your cores instead of trying to multi-thread - multi-threading and python just do not mix at the most fundamental level of the language.

Good Luck!

Comment: interesting... the issue is that the function i am trying to parallelize is like a webscraping function.... i would need it to occupy only few cpus, since most of the time, we are just waiting for response idly....

Comment: Because the biggest hold up is going to be IO waiting on requests I would recommend using an event driven requests. This can be done with built in python async or a event driven library like https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests - I like grequests because it makes these things easier. Batch a group of requests per process and make each process use grequests to avoid idling on IO request wait times while taking advantage of all the CPU cores.

Comment: ok.... so my application is much more complex than reading urls... I used another third party api to grep data, so we have to pass to a function...  i still need to keep it as func_now , arg_now... what can i do in this case?